# Which word has a silent B at the start?

Tags: single-word-requests, pronunciation, silent-letters

According to [this Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2018/dec/03/p-is-for-pterodactyl-t-is-for-tsunami-the-worst-alphabet-book-becomes-a-bestseller?CMP=fb_gu&fbclid=IwAR1NdezJ0uOLgL0c5gbUx2T6SV53Qh39dyuDE9xrPU2XNjVOtByBd6HvslU), about the book “[P is for Pterodactyl: The Worst Alphabet Book Ever](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pterodactyl-Worst-Alphabet-Book-Ever/dp/149266393X)”, there is one word in the English language which starts with a silent B. Unfortunately, they don’t tell us which word it is, and I’d quite like to know!

Comment: Something tells me that purchasing the book might tell you. ;)

Comment: @Laurel golly, that question is horrifically poorly titled!

Comment: I loved Troy McClure in [*'P' Is for 'Psycho'*](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/%22P%22_is_for_Psycho).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word is *[”Bdellium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bdellium)*” pronounced /ˈdɛliəm/. It is a semi-transparent resin, extracted from trees in Africa. It is used as an incense, and is sometimes passed off as myrrh, due to the price difference.

It is sometimes spelt “*Bdellion*”, and comes from the Greek “*βδέλλιον.*”

Comment: Here's the relevant page from the book: [link](http://www.cup.com.hk/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rsz_9781492674313.jpg).

Comment: And there's also the biological term _Bdelloid_, from the same root, which names [a class of rotifers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bdelloidea) that's distinguished for being parthenogenic (i.e, no males).